# How to count the frequency of each number in an int list?

Tags: c#

I have a list of player numbers(int list), I also have a number of laps (int laps). I have to enter the number of the player into a text box each time the player completes a lap. If valid, the player number entered into the text box will be sent to a list. However, each player number cannot be entered more than the number of laps.

I'm new to windows forms so I've only used lists to solve the problem, I've seen people use dictionary to solve similar issues but I'm not quite sure how to incorporate that to solve this issue.

```
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool result;
        int RunnerNumberInOrder;

        repeat2 = (getLaps2 * rows2);
        textBox2.Focus();

        //ReadPlayerNumber is the list that contains the list of the runners in the race. 
        //PlayerNumberInOrder int list is a global list and it is the list that the runners number order gets sent to if valid

        result = int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out RunnerNumberInOrder); //checks if the value entered is an integer


        if (result == false || !ReadRunnerNumbers2.Contains(RunnerNumberInOrder)) //if the value entered is not an integer an error message will pop up and ask to enter a valid number
        {
            label3.Text = "Please enter a valid player number from the list";

        }

        else
        {
            if (RunnerOrder.Contains(RunnerNumberInOrder))
            {

                count++;
            }

            if (count == getLaps2)
            {
                count = 0;
                label3.Text = "max laps for this runner has been entered";


                invalid.Add(RunnerNumberInOrder); //invalid is an int list that I used to send the numbers of the runners that have completed all laps. 


                textBox2.Clear();
                return;

            }

        }

        if (invalid.Contains(RunnerNumberInOrder))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Max number of laps for this runner has been entered");
            textBox2.Clear();
        }

        if (result == true && ReadRunnerNumbers2.Contains(RunnerNumberInOrder) && !invalid.Contains(RunnerNumberInOrder))
        {
            RunnerOrder.Add(RunnerNumberInOrder); //if number entered is valid, the it is added to the global variable             
            PlayerNumbersEntered++;
            label8.Text = RunnerNumberInOrder.ToString();//counts how many valid car numbers have been enterted
            textBox2.Clear();
        }


    }
```

The code I have kinda works but it sometimes only allows one number 2 times when the number of laps is 3 and sometimes will allow more than the laps entered. I want an error message to pop up when the player's number equals to the number of laps and the number shouldn't be allowed any further. I also have to use a text_change. Cheers for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue I see in your code I believe is the `count` variable which appears to be a global variable but you seems to use it like is count for specific RunnerNumbers.

The way I see it you could solve this by either creating a class of Runners that would have a number ID and the Count or, even simpler, to just get the count of that runner on the go as follows:

```
specificRunnerCount = RunnerOrder.Where(x => x == RunnerNumberInOrder).Count()
```

With this you could modify your code to something like this:

```
int specificRunnerCount = RunnerOrder.Where(x => x == RunnerNumberInOrder).Count();
if ((specificRunnerCount + 1) == getLaps2)  // +1 because we haven't added this number to the count yet.
{
    label3.Text = "max laps for this runner has been entered";
    invalid.Add(RunnerNumberInOrder); 
    textBox2.Clear();
    return;
}
// Continue code as is
```

Also, from your code, the part of code where you add a value to the invalid list: `invalid.Add(RunnerNumberInOrder);`, you use a `return` statement which ends the function. Due to this I don't see the need for you to check if the invalid list contains the runner number in `if (invalid.Contains(RunnerNumberInOrder))`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried this code out and it works, really appreciate your help. I did have to take away the +1 cause when i entered 3 laps it stopped taking in the runners number after 2 entries, the rest worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks again.